# How to transfer any specified column of a ListView

Tags: vb.net, listview

I kindly need help on how to transfer any specified column of a listview to a listbox or combobox. The code I am using is as follows.
It transfers only the first column of the Listview.
How do i specify the column I need to be transfered. Thank you.

```
For Each i As ListViewItem In .ListView1.Items
 .ComboBox1.Properties.Items.Add(i.Text)
Next
```

Comment: The ListView only looks like it is a grid, the other items are stored as subitems:  `lv.Items(n).Subitems(x).Text`

Comment: Thanx Plutonix, but it didnt work.
First and foremost its not a grid its a listview.
Sorry I added the ".Properties". I use DexExpress components which demands a ".properties.items.add" instead of straight forward "combobox.items.add".

Anyway, back to the problem at hand. Like I said, it did not work.

Comment: @dextergaisie He said it only looks like a grid as you referred to the ListView items as 'columns'. What he's saying is that ListViewItems have a top level Text property which is the first 'column' value. The other values are stored in a list called SubItems. Have a look in there for the other 'column' values.

Comment: I know he knows its not a grid. I just wanted to be clear on that.
I understand perfectly what  he meant.
Like I said. I did try it out and still have issues with it. i trying to still figure it out here.

Comment: Oh ok. I have figured it out. Thanx guys.

            Dim items As ListView.ListViewItemCollection
            Dim item As ListViewItem

            items = ListView1.Items
            For Each item In items
                combobox1.Items.Add(item.Text)
                combobox2.Items.Add(item.SubItems(1).Text)
            Next

Comment: ...which is *exactly* the code I gave you 3 hours earlier